# Safari on windows won't respect parent's element max-height

Tags: html, css, safari

In Safari the max-height of the parent element is not assumed to limit the height.

*This is how it renders in safari:*

[image]

The only workaround I found is to set the children element also with the max-height property.

Code:

```css
html {
  
  height: 100%;

}

body {

  height: 100%;

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}

.menu-ctn {

  border: 1px solid #ff6a00;

  max-height: 40px;

  height: 100%;

}

.menu-ctn ul {

  height: 100%;

  text-align: center;

  border: 1px solid #00ff21;

  max-height: inherit;    /* Safari only override */  <= Solution

}

.menu-ctn ul li {

  width: 24%;

  display: inline-block;

  vertical-align: middle;

  height: 100%;

  background-color: #0094ff;

  max-height: inherit;    /* Safari only override */  <= Solution
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu-ctn">
    <ul>
      <li>X</li>
      <li>Y</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

The expected result is that all the children elements of the parent where the max-height is set is respected:

[image]

Comment: Hi, the question is how to solve this issue so that the children's element respects the parent's max-height. It's working in IE, Chrome, Firefox but not in Safari.

Comment: The print is from my Safari version (Windows 5.1.7), what is yours?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? Please be as descriptive as possible.

Comment: Safari 7.1.3 and Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 on mac both browsers render it the same way. What is the expected result?

Comment: I have updated the question with the expected result

Comment: Are you looking for it to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/byh27jjg/ ? If not, please explain you request with greater description

Comment: @Alan I have tested your code and it present the same issue in Safari (only in Safari).

Comment: @Patrick The fiddle i added looks the same on all browsers my end...

Comment: @Patrick Use this one: https://jsfiddle.net/byh27jjg/1/ Are you still seeing the large blue boxes instead of contained ones?

Comment: @Alan I have updated the question with a print of the fiddle result in my Safari

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73175/discussion-between-alan-and-patrick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found that works perfectly in Safari for Windows without specifying any value in the height of any children's element is setting the property  max-height: inherit;

```
.menu-ctn ul {
    max-height: inherit;    /* Safari only override */
}

.menu-ctn ul li {
    max-height: inherit;    /* Safari only override */
}
```

Important note: The property must be added to all the descendants until the one element that we want to specify with the height.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it on Safari 7.1.3 and Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 on a mac both browsers render it the same way.

[image]

It appears to be a Safari on windows issue only. Try overriding the property with a media query that filters Safari 5+ from Chrome with a pseudoclass:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  /* Safari only override */
  ::i-block-chrome, .menu-ctn ul {
    height: 25%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**TL DR;**

Basically add the 2 lines of code to your existing ode:

`position: relative;` on `.menu-ctn`

`position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` on `.menu-ctn ul`

**Full example:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu-ctn">
    <ul>
        <li>X</li>
        <li>Y</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-ctn {
    border: 1px solid #ff6a00;
    height: 100%; max-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

.menu-ctn ul {
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #00ff21;
}

.menu-ctn ul li {
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #0094ff;
}
```

**LINK TO EXAMPLE**

Here is a link to a fiddle too: [LINK HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/byh27jjg/3/)

**All this results in:**

[image]